# How to remove extra whitespaces on django rest serializers

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have this problem atm where you serializer an object in django and it appears something like that.

```
{"title": "   remove   all spaces  "}
```

Within the serializer you can set extra_kwargs to trim fields. The results is the next

```
{"title": "remove   all spaces"}
```

Is there a way to remove those extra white spaces between the words "remove" and "all"??

Here is the serializer example:

```
class exampleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  
  class Meta:
     model = Example
     fields = ("title", )
     extra_kwargs = {"content": {"trim_whitespace": True}}
```

Comment: DRF doesn't have this feature. But, you can use SerializerMethodField

Comment: May I ask whether you want to remove spaces in `saving data` or `showing data`?

Answer (score 1):

add to_representation method to your serializer:

```
    def to_representation(self, data):
        data = super(exampleSerializer, self).to_representation(data)
        content = data['content']
        data['content'] = " ".join(content.split())
        return data
```